# Pushing Text into surface - Google Sketchup

Tags: 3d-design

In Google Sketchup, I have text on a surface that I'd like to push / pull so that the text is etched into, rather than placed upon the surface.  I can't seem to figure this out, the text disappears when I try to push it into the surface and I'm not quite sure what else to try.  Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried ungrouping the text? It's created as a group, and groups will not intersect/merge with any geometry outside the group.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in Graphic Design. The option is not available when specifying Off-Topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely you have to perform substract operation.
Take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inwYs-Fs-mM)

Extrude text and then substract it from the object to etch in.